# Install GCC 4.8+ on rhel x86_64 workstation 6

Tags: rhel, software-installation, gcc

I want to install gcc 4.8+, preferrably 4.9 on my **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.7 (santiago)**

I have a subscription to rhn-classic.

I tried installing devtoolset as given in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/3/html/User_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset-Subscribe.html

I list the available channels and instead of

```
rhel-x86_64-workstation-6-rhscl-1
```

I see

```
rhel-x86_64-workstation-6-rhscl-1-beta
```

so i add it using

```
 rhn-channel --add --channel=rhel-x86_64-workstation-6-rhscl-1-beta
```

And then when i run

```
yum install devtoolset-3
```

It says No package devtoolset-3 available.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the package is either not available, or using a different name, the first step is to find which is the case.  Use

```
yum list available |grep gcc
yum list available |grep devtoolset
```

to find whether you have misspelled the package name, or if gcc is available under a different name.  Check using `yum info` for the package.  Its description should show the relevant version information.

According to Red Hat's article *[What gcc versions are available in Red Hat Enterprise Linux?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19458)*, gcc 4.8 is available for Red Hat Enterprise 7.  If you need gcc 4.8 for RHEL 6, you may have to compile it yourself.

Further reading:

- [Installing GCC 4.8.2 on Red Hat Enterprise linux 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433142/installing-gcc-4-8-2-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-5)
- [How to Install gcc 4.7.x/4.8.x on CentOS](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos)
- [install latest gcc on rhel 6 x86_64](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/install-latest-gcc-on-rhel-6-x86-64)