# Install gcc 6.2.0 on RHEL6

Tags: rhel, gcc

I have an RHEL 6 server with gcc version 4.4.7. I wanted to update the gcc version to 6.2.0 . Yum update doesn't work. Also, [SO answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/install-latest-gcc-on-rhel-6-x86-64) for a similar question on  does not work.

Has anyone updated gcc in RHEL 6 x86_64 server recently?

Comment: RHEL 6 goes end of life in November 2020. There are two major versions newer than it out already (RHEL 7 and 8.) Those versions will pack newer compilers already. Just move on to a newer version.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you should not update the stock GCC of the OS, but install the newer GCC alongside it.

This is possible thanks to Software Collections, and it's [pretty simple](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-8/):

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

# On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install devtoolset-8
```

Now anytime you want to compile using newer GCC, type:

```
scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
```

Comment: I get the error                                                                                                   `Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
There was an error communicating with RHN.
RHN Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
rhn-plugin: Error communicating with server. The message was:

Error Class Code: 6001
Error Class Info: 
     RHN is in the process of being decommissioned and systems are no longer able to receive updates or make use of any RHN services.
     Please see https://access.redhat.com/articles/2979901 for more info.`

Comment: So why not follow the link in the error message and do as instructed: https://access.redhat.com/articles/2979901

Comment: that link points to a regular FAQ,am trying to find how else can I install gcc 6.2.0?

Comment: Try to look closely at the link. It is not a regular FAQ.

Comment: I looked,can't figure out how to overcome

Comment: The problem you’re facing is your system is not properly registered with RedHat and cannot receive updates. This is separate from the origin question. You should consult the page on how you can re/register your system.

Comment: I understand "why",there is no "how" to fix in the FAQ?all new systems are prohibited from registering ,so looking for an alternative way to install gcc 6.2.0

Comment: Any idea how to install gcc on Oracle Linux Server 6.6?

Comment: @user3682248 steps should be similar to CentOS. Oracle Linux is basically *also* a clone of RHEL, without a commercial subscription.